# how to get value of id and name from json response

Tags: php, json

I want to get value of id and name from the string given below in php. Can any body help me please.

> string(35400) "{"cities":[{"id":"3279","name":"Narasaraopet"},{"id":"1852","name":"Srirangapatna"}

Answer (score 1):

That's not really a valid json (missing `]}` at the end), but assuming you removed something from it just to post the question, do it like this:

```
$json = '{"cities":[{"id":"3279","name":"Narasaraopet"},{"id":"1852","name":"Srirangapatna"}]}';

$decoded = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($decoded['cities'] as $v){
    echo 'ID: ' . $v['id'] . '<br>';
    echo 'Name: ' . $v['name'];
    echo '<br><br>';
}
```

Output:

> ID: 3279 
>   Name: Narasaraopet
>
> ID: 1852
>   Name: Srirangapatna

---

To use it as objects, you can ommit the second argument, like so:

```
$decoded = json_decode($json);
```

Then you'd access the values object-like:

```
foreach($decoded->cities as $v){
    echo 'ID: ' . $v->id . '<br>';
    // ...
```

---

Read more about [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

---

Comment: beat me to it by 5 seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `json_decode()`, then you'll have an array.